# Program always crashes while creating a linked list from a file

Tags: c, file, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to write a program to put the first entry (entries are separated by a / ) of every line of a file into a linked list, but am miserably failing to do so.

The first "while" cycle runs well, but after that it completely crashes. I've tried multiple approaches but none worked so far. Any help would be appreciated as I'm stressing out a lot for not being able to do something this simple

thanks in advance!

```
t_local *cria_cabecalhoL(void){
    t_local *lista = (t_local*)malloc(sizeof(t_local));
    if (lista != NULL)
        lista->next = NULL;
    return lista;
}
typedef struct local{
    char *name;
    struct local *next;

}t_local;


void createlistlocals(t_local *header_l){
    FILE *fp;
    t_local *aux;
    t_local *aux1;
    aux1 = header_l;
    char *line = malloc(150*sizeof(char));
    char *name1 = malloc(150*sizeof(char));
    char c;
    fp = fopen("locais.txt","r");
    fgets(linha, 150, fp);
    while (strcmp(line, "end")!=0){
        puts(line);
        name =strtok(line, "/");
        puts(name1);
        aux->name = strdup(name1);
        aux->next = aux1->next;
        aux1->next= aux;
        aux1 = aux;
        fgets(line, 150, fp);
    }
    aux1 = header_l;

}


int main()
{
    t_local *header_l = cria_cabecalhoL();
    createlistlocals(header_l);

}
```

Comment: where is your `aux->name`, `aux` is pointing? Also please provide readable names to variables which will solve most of the errors.

Comment: The loop doesn't call the (amazingly named) `cria_cabecalhoL()` function to allocate new nodes, it seems to just juggle pointers which unfortunately doesn't magically create more nodes.

Comment: @unwind i translated the code (I'm not english) and that remainder of code stayed in portuguese xD but thanks, that didn't occur to me!

Comment: @unwind, first line in a `cria_cabecalhoL()` calls `malloc`.

Comment: @magras Yes, of course, but the loop that is expected to put each line of the read file into its own node, should of course allocate new nodes as it goes along. It doesn't.

Comment: you have to use malloc also for `aux` and `aux1`

Comment: @magras Yes, but only a single head node. `createlistlocals` does not as it tries to extend the list. Also where is `cabeca_l` from, is that a global?

Comment: @unwind, sorry, you are right. I missread your comment. My bad.

Comment: @JoãoTeixeira A complete English code would be really useful for general help/collaboration as a *runnable* example. Is `cabeca_l` from another piece of code? And `aux` doesn't seem to be initialised at all, so would expect that to crash the `while` loop as provided on the first iteration (although its undefined behavior, so maybe just overwrote something and made a mess).

Comment: @FireLancer ```cabeca_l``` is actually ```header_l```, got lost in translation, sorry about that

Comment: @JoãoTeixeira Should `aux1 = header_l;` be `aux = header_l;` as well?

Comment: @FireLancer in the last line?

Comment: what is `linha`? n what is it's declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a rough attempt to fix the most obvious problems with the structure.

```
t_local * createlistlocals(const char *filename)
{
    FILE * const fp = fpoen(filename, "rt");
    if (fp == NULL)
     return NULL;
    t_local *head = NULL;
    char line[150];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
    {
      const char * const slash = strchr(line, '/');
      if (slash == NULL)
        break;
      t_local * const node = malloc(sizeof *node);
      if (prev != NULL)
      {
        prev->next = node;
      }
      else
      {
        head = node;
      }
      *slash = '\0';
      node->name = strdup(line);
      prev = node;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
}
```

this also treats any non-matching line (e.g. a line without a slash) as the ending marker. This would include `end`.

As any code that does I/O and memory allocations, it could be made more robust. :)

This returns the list, with the first line's data in the first node and so on, and accepts a filename rather than hardcoding the filename and accepting an initial list node. This is more clear and useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this loop there appears to be a couple of errors.

- You create a single head node, but then you don't allocate additional memory for each of the lines as it is read
- It seems the first iteration uses an uninitialised pointer (maybe crash, or memory corruption).
- The next iteration seems to use a null pointer (almost certain crash).

Annotating the loop you had:

```
void createlistlocals(t_local *header_l){
    FILE *fp;
    t_local *aux;
    t_local *aux1;
    aux1 = header_l; // aux1 = head, aux is uninitialised
    char *line = malloc(150*sizeof(char)); // needs to be freed at the end
    char *name1 = malloc(150*sizeof(char));
    char c;

    fp = fopen("locais.txt","r");
    fgets(line, 150, fp); // assumuming linha == line

    // Note, there are ways to loop until the actual file end rather thna a "special line"
    while (strcmp(line, "end")!=0){ 
        puts(line);
        name1 =strtok(line, "/"); // Assuming the rest of the line is not important.
        puts(name1);

        // aux was uninitialised, so this will be undefined behaviour and either crash or
        // overwrite something (memory corruption) that may cause strange things later
        // (including crashes)
        aux->name = strdup(name1);
        // cria_cabecalhoL set header_l->next to null, so this is not actually creating a new node.
        // and the next loop will actually try to use null->name and that is basically garunteed
        // to crash on most systems.
        aux->next = aux1->next;

        aux1->next= aux;
        aux1 = aux;
        fgets(line, 150, fp); // This is duplicate, could be once at the start of the loop, maybe use for(...) loop
    }
    aux1 = header_l; // Note, assigning a local here at the end doesn't do anything

}
```

Fixing the linked-list related errors, and assuming a `t_local->name == NULL` is your end sentinel value.

```
t_local *cria_cabecalhoL(void){
    t_local *lista = (t_local*)malloc(sizeof(t_local));
    if (lista != NULL)
        lista->name = NULL; // no data, empty node
        lista->next = NULL;
    return lista;
}
void createlistlocals(t_local *header_l){
    FILE *fp;
    t_local *node = header_1;
    t_local *next;
    char *line = malloc(150*sizeof(char)); // needs to be freed at the end
    char *name1;

    fp = fopen("locais.txt","r");
    fgets(line, 150, fp);

    while (strcmp(line, "end")!=0){ 
        puts(line);
        name1 =strtok(line, "/");
        puts(name1);

        node->name = strdup(name1);
        // And create a new empty node for the next loop
        next = cria_cabecalhoL();
        node->next = next; // New node comes after the current one.
        node = next; // And now using the next node on loop

        fgets(line, 150, fp);
    }
}
```